# MVC + Multiple tenancy app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I have an MVC app that should change the Website title, and header color based on the domain the app is hit from. So I have a simple table setup in SQL as such:

**DomainName (PK), WebsiteTitle, HeaderColor**

Domain1.com, Website Title for Domain 1, #ebebeb

So I am trying to figure out the best way to return this information for each page view. Sure I can go ahead and lookup the site info in each model thats returned from the controller. But are there any other ways I can approach this? Maybe at a lower level in the stack?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. ActionFilters are one way, or in a BaseController.

You need to determine if *every* action requires this, or if only certain actions.

If you decide every action, create a controller base, inheriting from Controller, then overriding OnActionExecuting. In that method you can make you calls to fetch and add the data to viewdata. Like so:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Add("SiteTitle", "Site title");
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

If you prefer to use a base viewmodel that has this information, it would be best to override OnActionExectued where you can get access to the actions results, and modify the base model to set your values. Like so:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResultBase;
        var baseModel = (BaseViewModel) result.ViewData.Model;

        baseModel.SiteTitle = "Site Title";

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Depending if you want an inheritence chain for your viewmodels. Either works. You'll also notice that I just set the values. Use whatever source for values you need. If you are pulling them from the db, I would cache the values so that for every action you are not hitting the db for it.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot. It seems overriding the base controller seems like the way to go, I already had a basecontroller created but wanted a way to transfer the data to the view, ViewData makes sense.

Comment: If you have few things going into the viewdata, and only consuming them in a single master page or partial, it's a great way to go. However if you have a ton of data that you need to do this with, a base view model might be better. Depends how much you like strongly typed objects.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is fundamentally identical to swapping layout or master pages for mobile vs desktop browsers. However, instead of looking at the device caps in a web request to determine which layout to use, you'd check the domain of the request.

[See this article for a slightly complex (but thorough) overview of selecting mobile vs desktop views](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application). Much of what the author says is focused on detecting screen solution, etc., which doesn't directly apply to you, but the mechanism for selecting the master or layout page should be just what you're looking for.

Or, you can handle this through inheritance.

Implement a base controller, like so:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
   public string SiteTitle { get { .... } }
   public string HeaderColor { get { ... } }
   /// whatever other "global" properties you need

}
```

Then, each of your controllers inherit from `BaseController`

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var myTitle = SiteTitle; 
        /// then, do whatever you want with it
        return View();   
    }
}
```

In the property accessors in `BaseController`, read the title and whatever other properties you need from a `.settings` file or the `AppSettings` section in `web.config`.

`Controller` also provides events that can be used to set these properties so that you don't have to duplicate any code for getting those values into each view.